# redirect in jsp adding session ID to GET variables

Tags: jsp, session, redirect, jstl

A friend and I are trying to redirect to a welcome page with jstl. However when we use "<c:redirect url="welcome" />" our session id's are now stored in the GET variables.  He's sure that a better way to do things would be with javascript.  Is there a correct way in jstl?

Answer (score 1):

Using `c:redirect` is fine.

I suspect getting the session ID in the URL (ie GET variables) is due to server settings rather than the method you're using for redirect. For example in the [tomcat context](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html) definition you can override the default behaviour of using cookies for session id communication by setting `cookies=false`.

I'd discussed the javascript approach in a [blog post](http://dev-answers.blogspot.com/2008/10/redirect-from-jsp-page-to-another.html) but there's no real difference in network efficiency and as mentioned above I don't think this will make a difference to the session ID handling.